# Multiple ids in serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

need help.

How can I send a few id in a serializer so that I can process them later?

Im tried

```
ids = QuerysetParentProxyPKRelatedField(
    write_only=True, source='mymodel', pk_field=serializers.UUIDField())
```

And how the submitted json.

My thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for your time. Answer is elementary

```
ids = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.UUIDField())
```